# Multiple DB connection class

Tags: php, class, singleton, object

How do you create multiple DB connections using Singleton pattern? Or maybe there's better approach, to share the same class but multiple connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a Factory pattern to return the same instance for each connection, e.g.

```
ConnectionFactory::getInstance(ConnectionFactory::DEVELOPMENT);
```

Returns a `Connection` instance for a connection to the development database.

Instantiation of the `Connection` should only be performed by the `ConnectionFactory`, which can keep references to those instances in a static array, keyed by the connection type.  This avoid the singleton pattern, but ensures you only maintain a single instance of each `Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

Connection Pooling.

In case of java:

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/Code/JDCConnectionPool.java

This example just shows the way, you can implement it in still better way.

Comment: I gave the example in Java, I think you can convert the same to any language, I understand that you expect it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

How about dropping the Singleton pattern if what you want is multiple? Lately, Singleton has become an anti-pattern so you should probably drop it even if you need a single connection. Not to mention that extending Singleton in PHP is pretty hard for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, drop the singleton, then, I'd probably do something like this:

```
interface Connection_Interface
{
    public function connect();
    public function disconnect();
    public function exec($sql);
    // etc...
}

class Connection implements Connection_Interface
{
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database);
    public function connect();
    public function disconnect();
    public function exec($sql);
    // etc...
}
```

Then, another class that takes multiple connections:

```
class Connection_Multiple implements Connection_Interface
{
    protected $_connections = array();        

    public function __construct();
    public function add(Connection $connection);
    public function connect();
    public function disconnect();
    public function exec($sql)
    {
        // decide here which connection you want to use, then...
        return $connection->exec($sql);
    }
    // etc...
}
```

As both the single connection and the multiple connection classes implement the same interface you can use either in exactly the same way.

Comment: This is the composite pattern. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution:

```
class Database {
    private static $instances = array();

    public static function getInstance($connection='default') {
        if (!array_key_exists($connection,self::$instances)) {
            self::$instances[$connection] = new Database($connection);
        }
        return self::$instances[$connection];
    }

    private function __construct($connection) {
        $this->credentials = // getting credentials from config by $connection...
        $this->connect(); // connect using credentials
    }
}

$DB1 = Database::getInstance('development');
$DB2 = Database::getInstance('production');
```

Seems like works for me. Is this a Singleton pattern or something mixed?

Comment: No: a singleton ensures only one instance of a class exists which can be accessed globally.  Your design does limit instances of the class, but it is not always the same instance.  I hope the difference is distinct.